# Reference working on Overleaf but not locally

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I am using https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-michigan-dissertation-template-unofficial/tpnjzndnrzmf

I downloaded it to my own laptop and compiled it. The citation and reference are not working. But they are fine on Overleaf. I have a vague impression that this has something to do with compilation. I compiled twice using pdfLaTeX (WinEdt 10) but it is still the same. How shall I fix this problem?

Comment: you need to generate  the bibliography by running bibtex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What do you mean by "running"?

Comment: You have to compile with `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, and then `pdflatex` twice.  Overleaf takes care of all that for you behind the scenes.

Comment: One place to read up on that is https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex.  Search for "why are all those (repeated) processes required".

Comment: I don't use Windows so can't run WinEdt, and the documentation on its website is horrendously out of date, but I gather from looking at some Google Images that BibTeX is available through a 'TeX' menu and may have a keyboard shortcut. There might also be a (PDF)LaTeXify option (or maybe a plugin?) that automates things similarly to what Overleaf does. It would be easier to get help if you used a cross-platform editor with up to date documentation (texstudio, texmaker, texworks, etc.)

Comment: @frabjous winedt works fine. it has a good documentation and a good support mailing list. And running bibtex there is easy.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I dislike vendor lock-in and try never to recommend non-cross-platform software, but I didn't say it didn't work well; I said it's harder to get help for it. People on other platforms can't help. Developers who prefer other platforms can't ensure compatibility. If they have good documentation but for some unknown reason only have documentation from a 15 year old version online, that's not good. I only mention anything because I *wanted* to help Ypbor by specifying exactly needed to be done, but was frustrated by how hard it was for me to do, but I did what I could anyway.

Comment: @frabjous what do you mean with "15 years old"? The guide is from 2017 https://www.winedt.com/doc/QuickGuide.pdf and there is also a faq https://www.winedt.com/FAQs.html.  If you looked at winedt.org: that page is not from the winedt maintainer (and he is quite unhappy that it is not properly maintained).

Comment: He should remove the link to it then. The documentation on winedit.com is not adequate. Googling "bibtex site:winedt.com" only returns a couple results, none of which explain how to access BibTeX from its GUI. If you just google "bibtex winedit" you mainly find links here to SE or other people asking about it, or the org site.

Comment: Using WinEdt10 go to tab `TeX` then `Bibtex` or `Shift+Control +B`. Then  compile twice.